# Create a new font with letters from other fonts?

Tags: fonts

I would like to create a new font, and in this font I want to have some letters from other fonts.
For example: I want the "1" number from TAHOMA font, the "G" letter from ALIAS font etc.
Is there a program for this? Any free one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method would be a bit of a faff but it should work. Depends on the time you're willing to put in.

[This](http://www.yourfonts.com/) website allows you to create your own font from your handwriting. You download a sheet and fill it in. instead of printing it out you could open it in word and simply type in the appropriate font you wanted for each symbol. Print this out and scan it in.

You should then have a customised font of your liking.

It does cost up to $14.95 for a full font. $9.95 for just one sheet but the results are pretty good. I used it for a handwriting font of my own. The free preview's pretty good to determine if its what you're after.

Comment: this will require a lot of time :S.. I think I'll pass on this font creation and just use a similar one. Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: I think it may take about an hour depending on whether you know which fonts you already want