# A font has a letter in "U+007F" (delete) key, How can I get it?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, characters

I have a font and when I open it with Character Map, I see that there is a letter which is in the Delete Key! Here is a picture showing "U+007F: Delete":
[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

So how can I display this letter?

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 .. why?

Comment: Maybe you could add a `windows-7` tag to your post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Last update+1:* After Arjan's comment I've **finally found a way**; two in fact:

**First working option**

- In `Notepad` or `MS Word`  (tested with Word 97 (sic!) and Win XP's notepad) type  <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> which should just display as an empty box. Change the font to your font "QCF_BSML" and you should see the correct symbol:

[image: screenshot of MS Word 97 showing U+007F character from QCF_BSML font]

**Second working option**

Using [Arjan's JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/ufehef/5), you can make the character visible and then copy it to whereever you need it. Note that Windows Wordpad (in Win XP) *does not know how to deal with this character*, in contrast to Notepad and MS Word.

[image: screenshot of jsbin.com/ufehef/5]

**Old unsuccessful answers**

For further reference, all the ways this question *can't* be answered:

*First try* (FAIL)

Clicking the `Select` button and then `Copy` does *not* work to put this character into the clipboard.

*2nd try* (FAIL)

According to the [Unicode Character List](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f/index.htm) `Delete` can just be produced using <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>, but that does not work for this character.

*3rd try*  (FAIL)

I have successfully created a binary file containing only the byte `0x7F` using the hex editor [frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/). I could then open this file with [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordpad) (in Windows XP) and copy the character into a UTF-16 document, where it had the correct code (0x007F). However, when I try to change the font to QCF_BSML, it still displays just as a box, and not as the symbol visible in `charmap` (see screenshot in the question).

*4th try* (FAIL)

The insert special character dialog in "MS Word" silently skips this character.

*5th try*  (FAIL)

... using HTML in SuperUser:  (see source) doesn't work, but this is because SuperUser blocks the `font` tag. See above for how this works outside SuperUser.

Comment: On the other letters this worked, but only in this letter, after clicking the SELECT button, the COPY button remains disabled..

Comment: Nice. I am not on Windows, but curious: how does Windows show 0x7F for other fonts? Isn't that character in the question's screen capture just the word "delete", @Omar?

Comment: Maybe HTML *does* work? Surely Super User does not allow that `<font>` tag and silently ignores it, so SU cannot be used to test it. And I don't have the font installed. But maybe [this JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ufehef) shows it after all? (I guess it shouldn't, as it feels like an erroneous font, but please check, @Omar.)

Comment: @Arjan: I had the same thought, so I've tried with the font Omar uses offline on my PC. It didn't work, but now after a reboot the problem is solved. Maybe just Opera needed a restart to re-read the font list... silly me. I'll update the answer...

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer. I have another question: Can I edit the font file and move this letter to another button to make it easier for other people?

Comment: You've asked that other question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/339002/create-a-new-font-with-letters-from-other-fonts) I think, but unfortunately I don't have an answer for that.